# A mixture of discrete and continuous components

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, zero-inflation

Suppose that random variable $X$ is sampled from Bernoulli with probability $\pi$. Let $Y\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and denote $Z=XY$. Then, when $X=0$, $Z$ equals 0 (and this happens with probability $1-\pi$) and, when $X=1$, $Z$ follows $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (and this happens with probability $\pi$). I want to calculate mean, variance, density, ... of $Z$. To do so, I write
$$Z=(1-\pi) N(0, 0) + \pi N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
By writing like this, I can apply general results for mixture of distribution to. My questions are:

1. Can I use N(0, 0) here to ease my calculation? Is there any better way?
2. Is there any place in the literature that extensively discuss this kind of distribution?

Comment: This is related to the Heckman two stage model.

Comment: This is essentially a zero-inflated normal distribution. I took the liberty of adjusting the tags (I don't really think this is usefully described as a Gaussian mixture, because one of the components is, well, degenerate). Somewhat surprisingly, [we seem to have no useful threads carrying both tags]([zero-inflation] [normal-distribution]), but looking for "zero inflation" might help you in your literature search, though it *is* more commonly applied to discrete distributions, like the zero-inflated Poisson.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I thought about this way of writing to make the calculation easier but actually it is just for convenient, it does not affect the calculation. I have posted a related question, where I mention that convenient writing. Anyway, I have difficulty to apply the CLT. If you have any idea, please post your comments here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560005/central-limit-theorem-for-dependent-binary-related-variable. Thank you!