# Central limit theorem for dependent binary-related variable

Tags: central-limit-theorem, independence, bernoulli-distribution, iid, dependent-variable

Let $Y\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and given sample size $n$, we have an ***iid*** sample $\{Y_1, ..., Y_n\}$. We sample $X$ (size $n$) from Bernoulli with probability $\pi$. Denote $Z_i=X_iY_i$. Then, when $X_i=0$, $Z_i$ equals 0 (and this happens with probability $1-\pi$) and, when $X_i=1$, $Z_i$ follows $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (and this happens with probability $\pi$). Thus $Z_i$ is a mixture of two distributions, which for convenient, I write as follows:
$$Z_i=(1-\pi) N(0, 0) + \pi N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
It follows that $E(Z_i)=\pi\mu$ and $Var(Z_i)=\pi(\mu^2+\sigma^2) - (\pi\mu)^2$.

Since $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ is ***iid***, $\{Z_1, ..., Z_n\}$ is ***iid*** and I can apply the CLT to establish the asymptotic distribution of $\overline{Z}$.

**Suppose now** we constrain that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i=n\pi$. Marginally, $X_i\sim Bern(\pi)$ but $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ is **no longer** independent. Therefore $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ is not ***iid***. As a result, $\{Z_1, ..., Z_n\}$ is not **iid**.

Is there any **existing version of the CLT** that I can apply here? If not, how can I modify the CLT so that I can apply it here?

**Edit**: To sample $X_1, ..., X_n$ so that their sum equals to $n\pi$, I use the following R statement:

```
sam$X = sample(c(rep(0, as.integer(n * (1-pi))),rep(1, as.integer(n * pi))))
```

I use as.integer just to be sure that the product is an integer. In fact, I choose $n$ and $\pi$ so that I am sure they are integers.

Comment: How do you reconcile the two  apparently contradictory statements "sum ... is fixed" and "marginally ,,, Bernoulli$(\pi)$"? The issue is that the first statement implies $\pi=n_1/n$ but you haven't made any such assumption.  This suggests your problem statement is incomplete concerning exactly what distribution $(X_i)$ has.  Are you perhaps trying to say that the $i$ for which $X_i=1$ can be considered a random subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ among those of size $n_1$? If that's the case, then it's simple to apply the usual CLT, *provided you tell us how $n_1$ varies as $n$ grows large.*

Comment: You are correct. I have edited. I do not use $n_1$ anymore. Indeed, that sum equals to $n\pi$. When $n$ goes to infinity, that sum also goes to infinity.  Could you open my question or do I need to post a new post?

Comment: Thus, the sum of the $Z_i$ ought to be distributed approximately as a mixture of $0$ (with weight $1-\pi$) and a normal distribution with mean $n\pi\mu$ and variance $n\pi\sigma^2$ (with weight $\pi$).  That makes the result clear and it remains only to formulate and demonstrate it using the usual CLT.

Comment: @whuber: It follows that $\sum Z_i=\sum X_iY_i = \sum Y_i$ (where $X_i$=1). This is equal to $n\pi\mu$ (in average), hence I do not see that the sum of $Z_i$ can take value 0 (with weight $\pi$). Anyway, I am not sure to apply the CLT since $\{Z_i\}$ is not iid.

Comment: I see--I was mistaken about the mixture.  Nevertheless, you apply the CLT to the $Z_i$ for which $X_i=1.$ The others introduce nothing into the sum and can be neglected.

Comment: @TrungDung I'm confused about the role of $n$. Currently you seem to assume that $n\pi$ is integer, but of course this can at best hold for a subsequence of $n\to\infty$. Is this what you want your CLT to run over - despite needing the full sequence for defining your observations? No constraint active for $n\pi$ not integer, I guess?

Comment: @whuber. You are right!

Comment: @ChristianHennig. Your comment makes sense. Indeed, if, e.g., $\pi=0.5$ then we can only be sure that $n\pi$ is integer when $n$ is even. With $n$ is odd, I think that the distribution does not change much if we take $\sum A_i = [n\pi]$ (the closest integer) (for $n$ sufficient large). What do you think?

Comment: @TrungDung Ultimately you need to decide what you want yourself. $\sum X_i=[n\pi]$ or something may in fact make the sequence (almost) deterministic. You could also accept what I've said and only look at those observations for which $n\pi$ is integer. I'm not 100% sure but the argument of whuber may apply in any case.